# What's the difference between Convnets hardware architectures designed for training and those designed for inference?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, cpu-architecture, hardware-acceleration

Do I have to hardware-implement the `gradient descent` algorithm to design a **CNN training accelerator**? or I just need to implement, like the case in inference, the convolutional engines (array of multipliers and accumulators), pooling and ReLU.

In other words, can I build a CNN training accelerator to just receive the feed forward operations and let, for example, the software and the computer processor to do the gradient descent job, update the network parameters and accordingly give instructions back to the accelerator?

Comment: How should we know what you need if we don't know the purpose? Do you need an accelerator for inference or for training?

Comment: @Leeor In the description of my question, I'm asking about a training accelerator.

Comment: Well, if you want to accelerate training, than you need a training accelerator.  The gradient decent or equivalent phase is the real heavy-lifting, what's the point in accelerating the forward phase alone? Either way, the question is a little vague.

Comment: The question may be broad. I should have probably asked  which is more computationally intense, the gradient descent/ feed backward  job or the feed forward one. And accordingly, I can decide what i really need to accelerate more importantly to build a training accelerator. Thanks anyway.